# AngularJS: preserving insertion order with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I'm implementing an autocomplete system with ng-repeat. Basically, I have an array of objects which feeds an ng-repeat. I noticed that when I insert new things in to the array, the insertion order is not preserved. For example

Insertion order

A - B - C

ng-repeat rendering order

A - C - B

(each of A, B, C is an object with 2 keys 'id' and 'name')

A closer look suggested to me that this behavior is caused by how $$hashKey is generated. 'C' somehow got a hash key that is smaller than 'B' so it comes before 'B' even though it's the opposite with insertion order.

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `track by` syntax ( requires angular.js **>=1.2** )

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items track by item.id">
```

Read this article: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2556-Using-Track-By-With-ngRepeat-In-AngularJS-1-2.htm

---

From [ngRepeat docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngRepeat):

> #### variable in expression track by tracking_expression`
>
> You can also provide an optional tracking function which can be used to associate the objects in the collection with the DOM elements. If no tracking function is specified the ng-repeat associates elements by identity in the collection. It is an error to have more than one tracking function to resolve to the same key. (This would mean that two distinct objects are mapped to the same DOM element, which is not possible.) Filters should be applied to the expression, before specifying a tracking expression.