# Loading a lot of elements for ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, performance, angularjs, optimization, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a page that needs to load thousands of rows from an API (via an AngularJS service). Rather than do it all at once, I decided to load in 100 at a time, ala:

```
$scope.fetchTransactions = function(page) {
  TransactionService.get($scope.product, page).then(function(response) {
    $scope.transactions = $scope.transactions.concat(response.data.transactions);

    if(response.data.transactions.length > 0) {
      $timeout(function() {
        $scope.fetchTransactions(page + 1);
      }, 1000);
    }
  });
}
$scope.fetchTransactions(1);
```

This loads 100 transactions at a time. In my view, I have a table and a `tr` that looks like:

```
<tr class="fade-in-repeat" ng-repeat="transaction in transactions | orderBy: ['-txid', '-time']>
```

When it loads, the browser freezes for a second here and there. What can I do to speed that up?

** SAMPLE JSON for one transaction **

```
{
  "__v":1,
  "_id":"52e7c99dc22c6f16aee227e7",
  "blockhash":"00000000186a147b91a88d37360cf3a525ec5f61c1101cc42da3b67fcdd5b5f8",
  "blockheight":51741,
  "blockorder":601,
  "blocktime":1271619803,
  "locktime":0,
  "time":1271619803,
  "txid":"0a37858c0d00af40cce12256133d7e743c42ffb345e8826d3e6700c6d0745413",
  "version":1,
  "vin_total":27.34,
  "vout_total":27.34,
  "updatedOn":"2014-01-28T15:15:41.508Z",
  "indexedOn":"2014-01-28T15:15:41.508Z",
  "vout_addresses":[
    "1CQXTdQYwquztA6jry2NjDVfRoizPco5rR",
    "1XPTgDRhN8RFnzniWCddobD9iKZatrvH4"
  ],
  "vout":[
    {
      "n":0,
      "spent_txid":"60417dc3a354910719c32eb3e70f14f971807cbb3a3c6b0b1cccc7b09c838115",
      "value":27.33,
      "scriptPubKey":{
        "reqSigs":1,
        "type":"pubkeyhash",
        "addresses":[
          "1CQXTdQYwquztA6jry2NjDVfRoizPco5rR"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "n":1,
      "spent_txid":"77036fa2ac75212be1ce93e8e1008d5cb2bcbb51aa560a5fe29c9c1423bbd00e",
      "value":0.01,
      "scriptPubKey":{
        "reqSigs":1,
        "type":"pubkeyhash",
        "addresses":[
          "1XPTgDRhN8RFnzniWCddobD9iKZatrvH4"
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "vin":[
    {
      "_id":"52e7c99dc22c6f16aee227e8",
      "sequence":4294967295,
      "txid":"c0eea97dc593f059f90630839557a5df1c3c8d7b73e01e5c8c01b89764705583",
      "vout":1,
      "meta":{
        "address":"13QaytjPv9cAJbDjGZCKCthxd8kHtSWKHE",
        "amount":27.34
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you post a JSON representation of a transaction object  ?

Comment: Where is the `product_id` field?

Comment: I updated the field accordingly

Comment: Can you look @ below url https://www.exratione.com/2013/12/considering-speed-and-slowness-in-angularjs/ may be help

Use Pagination, and Using Smaller Page Sizes or Infinite Scrolling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In angular when you work with thousands of rows using `ng-repeat` is a bad idea since it adds $watch to each element and as a result has a direct impact on performance.

so for now the best thing you could do is to work with the DOM your self,
I would suggest creating your own directive and iterate the elements using the native JavaScript API or JQuery, it doesn't matter, also i would suggest using [CreateDocumentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createDocumentFragment) for DOM manipulations ([why](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/gilf/2013/03/28/quick-tip-too-much-dom-manipulations-can-hurt-you/) would you want to use CreateDocumentFragment).

**Example:**

```
  mainApp.directive("myRepeater", function () {
   var LIST_ITEM = "li";
        return {            
            restrict: "A",
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                var rawElm = element[0];        
                scope.$watch(attrs.source, function(newValue) {
                    if (!newValue || !newValue.length || newValue.length === 0) return;

                    // wipe the previous list
                    rawElm.innerHTML = "";
                    var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();

                    newValue.forEach(function (item) {
                        var listItemNd = document.createElement(LIST_ITEM);
                        var textNd = document.createTextNode("your text");
                        listItemNd.appendChild(textNd);
                        frag.appendChild(listItemNd);
                    });

                    rawElm.appendChild(frag);
                });
            }
        };
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Try to pre-filter it like so (inject `$filter`):

```
$scope.fetchTransactions = function(page) {
  TransactionService.get($scope.product, page).then(function(response) {

    if(response.data.transactions.length > 0) {

      var transactions = $scope.transactions.concat(response.data.transactions);
      $scope.transactions = $filter('orderBy')(transactions, ['-txid', '-time']);

      $timeout(function() {
        $scope.fetchTransactions(page + 1);
      }, 1000);
    }
  });
}
```

#### And also use `track by`:

```
<tr class="fade-in-repeat" 
    ng-repeat="transaction in transactions track by transaction ._id">
```

Comment: What does `track by` do?

Comment: Check my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21243648/angularjs-preserving-insertion-order-with-ng-repeat/21243851#21243851

Comment: This is still causing browser freezing during the loading. I removed the `filter` altogether to see if that was the bottleneck

Comment: Maybe you have tons of bindings inside the repeater. angular dirty checks each one of them with each $digest. If this is the case you should provide more information of what bindings you need, and probably also a plunker so the problem could be reproduced.